# Unexcepted failed Gavel/Dredd test

Tags: testing, automated-tests, dredd

Can anyone help me figure out why this Dredd test fails? It looks fine to me:

```
fail: GET /device/2/battery duration: 260ms
fail: body: Real and expected data does not match.

request: 
body: 

headers: 
    User-Agent: Dredd/0.6.0 (Darwin 14.3.0; x64)

uri: /device/2/battery
method: GET


expected: 
headers: 
    connection: Keep-Alive
    content-length: 18
    content-type: text/plain

body: 
BATTERY REQ QUEUED

statusCode: 200


actual: 
statusCode: 200
headers: 
    connection: Keep-Alive
    content-length: 18
    content-type: text/plain
    date: Tue, 09 Jun 2015 19:01:59 GMT

body: 
BATTERY REQ QUEUED
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These suspicious errors are commonly caused by trailing newline character in expected or real body. Try to parse your blueprint with the [CLI API Blueprint parser](https://apiblueprint.org) and see what Dredd expects exactly.

There is [a hint for a workaround for this in the documentation](https://dredd.readthedocs.org/en/latest/hooks/#remove-traling-newline-character-for-in-expected-plain-text-bodies).

Comment: Thank you! It was a newline character in the expected body!